# Access Magento SOAP API via JavaScript: What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, magento, soap

i'm currently trying to access the SOAP API of a my magento store with no success. i have created a soap user and role in backend and tested them via xmlrpc login.
Same-Origin-Policy is not an issue. i get the wsdl via the url myshop.com/api/?wsdl

i have tried [jquery soap client](http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/):

```
$.soap({
    url: 'http://my-shop.de/api/',
    method: 'login',
    data: {
        username:'soap_username',
        apiKey:'soap_userpass'
    },

    success: function (soapResponse) {
        alert("yes!!");
    },
    error: function (SOAPResponse) {
        alert(SOAPResponse.toString());

    }

})
```

returning a 404 and i can't figure out why.

in addition i have tried [javascript soap client](http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/):

```
var url = 'http://myshop.de/api/';
var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
pl.add("username", 'soap_username');
pl.add("apiKey", 'soap_userpass');

SOAPClient.invoke(url, "login", pl, true, HelloTo_callBack);

function HelloTo_callBack(r) {
    alert(r.toString());
};
```

returning a 500 internal server error. again, i have no clue what is going wrong here.
can anyone give me a hint about what i am missing?

any help or hint appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok found the problem!
it was the maintenance mode. Even my ip was whitelisted and i could browse the store and backend normally, somehow the soap api calls got messed up. So working code for me is:

```
$.soap({
    url: 'http://my-shop.de/api/?wsdl',
    method: 'login',
    data: {
        username:'soap_username',
        apiKey:'soap_userpass'
    },

    success: function (soapResponse) {
        alert("yes!!");
    },
    error: function (SOAPResponse) {
        alert(SOAPResponse.toString());

    }

})
```

(note changed URL)

Comment: I get this error, when trying your code:

OPTIONS http://192.168.1.61/magento/index.php/api/?wsdllogin jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-2.1.4.js:8630jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.js:8166SOAPEnvelope.send @ jquery.soap.js:226$.soap @ jquery.soap.js:96(anonymous function) @ jquery.html:12
jquery.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.61/magento/index.php/api/?wsdllogin. Invalid HTTP status code 500
jquery.soap.js:388 Uncaught Error: Unexpected Content: undefined